# Graphql Syntax Error: Expected Name, found "{"

Tags: graphql

I wrote a `query` of GraphQL.

```
import { gql } from '@apollo/client';
export const GET_CART_DETAILS_QUERY = gql`
    query GetProductSizeChartQuery($sku:String!) {
        getProductSizeChart(sku:$sku){
          heading:{
          label
          values: {
          sku
          attribute_id
          size_id
          size
          is_stock
          }
          }
          sizeChart:{
          title
          options:{
          inch
          cm
          }
          }    
          optionLabel:{
          label
          }
        }  
    }
`;
```

And I am calling it as :

```
    const {
        data: ProductSizeChartData,
        loading: ProductSizeChartLoading,
        error: ProductSizeChartError
    } = useQuery(GET_CART_DETAILS_QUERY, {
        variables: { sku: item?.product?.sku }
    });
```

But I am getting an error :

`Syntax Error: Expected Name, found "{".`

I am not able to detect what is wrong here. Please help !

Comment: All occurrences of `:` inside the `getProductSizeChart(sku: $sku) {` block should be removed. Nesting should be defined as `heading {`, **not** `heading: {`. Check the [GraphQL query documentation](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/).